# Is it possible to catch what is printed on browser console?

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, rspec

I run Ruby/RSpec+Selenium. During the tests, the JavaScript code prints some info to the browser console. I would be interested to get that output from my code (in Ruby). Would it be possible (even with some limitations)?

Of course, if possible the browser-independent way is preferred.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a script file with the below content and include this on top of every page before any other JS that logs to console:

```
(function(old)
{
   console.log = function(str){  
                    //save the str in a hidden field on page
                    old.call(console,str);          
                 }

})(console.log);
```

The hidden field will have all the log data which can be posted back to server.
Same can be done for other console methods like error etc

Comment: is `console.log()` good for every browser? if not, is there any tech tip for implementing it in a browser-independent way please?

Comment: console.log is there in IE 9, FF, Chrome and Safari. You can check which method the test javascript uses to print the logs and apply the same trick to those methods